# На что влияют и что значат данные настройки при публикации приложения .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

Хотелось бы узнать, на что влияют и для чего нужны данные параметры публикации приложения.

[image: Параметры профиля публикации Visual Studio]

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/core/deploying/

Comment: Так то там вроде по смыслу вполне понятно, ну кроме деталей каких-то.